# For Loop Skipping Lines?

Tags: java

I'm still a bit new to Java, so sorry if this is a silly question. Basically, I'm making a pizza program, so when I order with friends it calculates how much we all owe (for example, if two of us are in on a $4 pizza, we each pay $2 and add that to our own totals). I decided to make a new object type "Person" and an actual object "people". I made it an array and had each person as an index of the array. So far, I just want to make an index for each person and add a name for each. However, when my loop is first run, it skips the lines making the first index. The next ones run just fine. Any reason why and/or is my method for making this ineffective?

Main Class:

```
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

double costItem;
int numPeopleIn;
Person[] people;
int y;

System.out.println("Welcome to Pizza Cost!\nTo start, how many people are in on this order?");

people = new Person[scan.nextInt()];

System.out.println("Type their names, pressing ENTER between names.");
for (int x = 0; x<people.length; x++) {
    System.out.println("ran");
    people[x] = new Person();
    people[x].name = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("hit the end");
}
```

Person Class:

```
package me.chris.pizzacost;
public class Person {

String name = "blank";
double cost;

}
```

Thanks so much in advance,
-Chris

Comment: @immibis that did it, just added a random scan.nextLine() before the loop and it worked. Any reason why that happened? Also, do you suggest I use the array method I'm doing now?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've initialized your array, you need to consume an extra new line

```
people = new Person[scan.nextInt()];
scan.nextLine(); // ignored
```

This happens because `nextInt()` only returns the number of people to you (the actual `int`) and leaves the `enter` pressed right after it which then interferes with your program by getting scanned on the first iteration of your `for` loop.

Comment: that worked, thanks so much. do you think my method of object arrays is effective or is it fine for this?

Comment: It's fine for simple programs. Later you could move on to a `List<Person>` which could grow dynamically in the loop i.e. until the user says "okay, no more persons need to be added.." and you just `break` out of the `loop` then.